# I can't change table's position

Tags: html, css, css-position

I created table and I want to change it's position. At this point, I can't change position at all, so I believe direction doesn't matter. I've tried margin and padding on .first_table(I gave table this class), but it doesn't work at all. I tried changing display property as well as position property, but they didn't work either. They only worsened the situation. Though it is possible that those two properties only worsened the situation because I couldn't use them properly. Here are css and html codes of table:

```css
.first_table{
  color: #ad0720;
}

.first_table th h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ad0720;
}

.first_table td {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1em;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #0E1119;
}

.first_table {
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 50 50;
  display: table;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.first_table td, .first_table th {
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-left: 2%;
}


.first_table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #323C50;
}


.first_table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #2C3446;
}

.first_table th {
  background-color: #1F2739;
}

.first_table td:first-child {
  color: #FB667A;
}

.first_table tr:hover {
  background-color: #464A52;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 6px -6px #0E1119;
}

.first_table td:hover {
  background-color: #FFF842;
  color: #403E10;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: #7F7C21 -1px 1px, #7F7C21 -2px 2px, #7F7C21 -3px 3px, #7F7C21 -4px 4px, #7F7C21 -5px 5px, #7F7C21 -6px 6px;
  transform: translate3d(6px, -6px, 0);
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-timing-function: line;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .container td:nth-child(4),
  .container th:nth-child(4) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="first_table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>უნარები</th>
          <td>Python</td>
          <td>Web Development</td>
          <td>Red Hat/CentOS</td>
          <td>Algorithms & Data Structures</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>შეფასება</th>
          <td>⭐⭐⭐</td>
          <td>⭐,⭐/2</td>
          <td>⭐</td>
          <td>⭐⭐⭐</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I don't know if I understand your problem, because you can easily move the table giving her, e.g., `position: absolute;` and  `left: 20%;`

Comment: `margin: 50 50;` — Use a validator. Lengths require units.

Comment: "I want to change it's position" — In what way?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the table in a `<div>` with an id or class, then add to it a `position:relative` and margin/padding. Tested, works.